# Why this delete[] action error?

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error, heap-memory, delete-operator

I delete a wchar_t array after use it, but fail:

```
const wchar_t t1[] = L"A string";
const wchar_t* t2 = L"Other string";

wchar_t* w = new wchar_t[wcslen(t1) + wcslen(t2) + 1];

int len = swprintf_s(w, wcslen(w), L"%s%s", t1, t2);
w[len] = 0;

delete[] w;
```

I fail at `delete[] w;`, with error `write to the end of heap buffer`, but I check at Locals that `w` is ok:

[image: My error]

How to fix this error?

Comment: C doesn't have a `delete` operator. Retagging this as C++.

Comment: You probably have UB elsewhere. Present an actual testcase, as you were instructed to do in How To Ask.

Comment: `swprintf_s(w, wcslen(w), ...` `w` is initially an uninitialised buffer, so calling `wcslen` on it is incorrect. You want to pass the **size** of the buffer to `swprintf_s`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter you're right. that is the error

Comment: @Sakura Don't edit your question stating as _solved_. Provide an answer with the solution instead.

Comment: Do not post images of text. Copy/paste the text instead!

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the error is, as @Jonathan Potter point out:

> swprintf_s(w, wcslen(w), ... w is initially an uninitialised buffer, so calling wcslen on it is incorrect. You want to pass the size of the buffer to swprintf_s